# Kotlin - Dagger 2 - Component is not generated by Dagger 2 in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm stuck at this problem when I move from java to Kotlin. Dagger is not generating the DaggerComponent class. I've tried many ways to fix this. This is my Code :

**app.gradle** :

...

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

...

dependencies {
    ...

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

   ...

    compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my **project.gradle** :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    ext.support_version = '27.1.1'
    ext.glide_version = '4.7.1'
    ext.glide_slider_version = '1.3.2'
    ext.dagger_version = '2.17'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

       ...
```

And finally this is my component interface code :

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, DatabaseModule::class))
interface DIComponent {
    fun inject(app:App)
}
```

I think that i did it correctly, I declare all the required code with the correct annotations. I've did clean and rebuild the project but it still doesn't work. i did the invalidate caches and restart etc. it's still doesn't work.

Did I make a mistake when declaring the component? Or is there something wrong with my Android Studio. I don't have any idea about this. It's really confusing me and made me stressful.

Comment: did you check if somewhere under the `build` folder you have the generated classes? By default that folder is excluded by the IDE from being indexed, so you won't be able to use them even if files are physically present in the file system.

Comment: I can't find it under the build folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add @Singleton

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, DatabaseModule::class))
interface DIComponent {
    fun inject(app:App)
}
```

Comment: Please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the aforementioned solutions doesn't work and you can't still see any generated `DaggerComponent`:

Sometime the issue is deceptive. It comes from Android Studio that *generates* the sources as expected in the `build` folder but doesn't refresh this folder, your sources does what has changed in the `build` folder.

You'll have to manually force Android Studio to `reload the sources from Disk` . You can achieve that by finding the appropriate action or right clicking on the incriminated module.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed my problem by adding @Singleton to my component and then add this to my app gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
```

I dont know with one solved my problem. But i saw that in the message when the gradle is finished building there are some warning and one of the warning is that there is a problem with the kotlin compiler in data binding. So fixed that and i fixed my problem too. Thanks .